# BigQuery: distinct values in key column

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I have a table with event_params.key column

I want to see all possible values in this column:

[image]

When I try to select distinct values:

```
SELECT  distinct event_params.key FROM `data.analytics.events_*`
```

I get an error...

So I know how to extract values, but for the next step, I need to know all possible distinct values and their types in the key column ( int, float, string..)

How to do it?

Comment: Unnext() is the solution for your problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `unnest()`:

```
SELECT ep.key, COUNT(*)
FROM `data.analytics.events_*` e CROSS JOIN
     unnest(event_params) ep
GROUP BY ep.key;
```

Note:  This can be quite expensive if your data is large.